# Command line Add retina display extension to all image into a folder

Tags: xcode, macos, shell, command-line

What's the command line to add a retina display extension (@2x) to all images into specific folder : 
Ex : eximg.png -> eximg@2x.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: only png? how did you list those "image files"?

Comment: All image are in the same folder and they are all png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This also works if the filenames contain spaces or special characters:

```
for f in *.png; do mv "$f" "${f%.png}@2x.png"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

if your filename doesn't have special letters (e.g. spaces), this line will print those `mv cmd` for you:

```
 ls *.png|xargs -n1|sed -r 's/(.*)(.png)$/mv & \1@2x\2/'
```

and if all those commands are ok, you could pipe the output to `|sh` to rename your files.

Edit

```
 ls *.png|xargs -n1|sed 's/\(.*\)\(.png\)$/mv & \1@2x\2/'
```

Comment: I got illegal option -- r error also there is some images with SCHAR like Virgin-Islands,-British.png

Comment: @Molwiko my sed is gnu sed. yours maybe bsd sed? no experience of OSX. but you could try to remove the `-r` and for each `(` or `)`, change them into `\(` and `\)` and comma and dash are not problem

Comment: I tried  ls *.png | xargs -n1 | sed  's/(.*)(.png)$/mv & \1@2x\2/' but it didn't work error -> sed: 1: "s/(.*)(.png)$/mv & \1@2 ...": \1 not defined in the RE

Comment: I got the following output on the command line :
mv Cook-Islands.png Cook-Islands@2x.png
mv Costa-Rica.png Costa-Rica@2x.png
xargs: unterminated quote   --> no files created

Comment: you need to pass the output (mv cmds) to `|sh` to do the rename

Comment: sh: line 52: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: line 52: `mv Cocos-(Keeling)-Islands.png Cocos-(Keeling)-Islands@2x.png'

Comment: Also I got images with imagename@2x@2x@2x.png.